# Hide Android keyboard key preview

Tags: android

What I'm looking to do is hide only the popups that show what key you are currently pressing while using a soft keyboard. Is this possible? I am creating my own new keyboard which will have no need for them.

From what I think I understand, the picture below is the actual popup keyboard that you can choose to show using `android:popupKeyboard` and `android:popupCharacters` in the `Keyboard.Key` XML.

[image: Popup Android Keyboards]

But the image below is **not** the same (also see [this picture](http://www.cnet.com/i/bto/20090812/touchpal_cnet_270x404.png)). Is there a way to turn the following off, using XML or even programmatically?

[image: Android Keyboard Popups]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After reading [a little bit of the actual android keyboard source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java):

What I was referring to was the "key preview", which is "a popup that shows a magnified version of the depressed key." By default the preview is enabled, but to disable it, simply enough, is `setPreviewEnabled(boolean previewEnabled)`. Which is a method from the `KeyboardView` class. [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html).

Comment: hi @Whymarrh if you have developed on your own, I am also working on softkeyboard where i am facing problem, where i want to display multiple characters on one key as shown in your above first keyboard q below 1. I have tried upon me to display multiple/multiline characters on key using label then i got output as shown this link "http://puu.sh/4Xmz1.png". So can you please guide how to display multiple characters on key...

Comment: @Aniket you can see my full source code online on GitHub: http://git.io/mM7pPQ. You can try using Unicode characters to display what you need on the key, as per this file: http://git.io/SXo3GA.

Comment: It worked for me. I just had to use the method "setPreviewEnabled(boolean)" from the "KeyboardView" class.

Answer (score 9):

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
     mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
}

public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(true); //Change to false if you want remove too for the Del key when it's pressed
}
```

Additionally, To get the view and universally disable the preview from within a custom class extending `InputMethodService`

```
    private KeyboardView mInputView;
    @Override
    public KeyboardView onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        mInputView .setPreviewEnabled(false);
        return mInputView;
    }
```