# Popup layout in soft keyboard for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am currently studying soft keyboard implementation in android. One thing I am confused with is where to implement the popup little square when you press any key (I attach two example below).

I have read through the sample app "Soft Keyboard" provided in SDK, it has this feature, but I can't find which piece of code implements it.

Any ideas how I could implement/modify it?

[*Sample app "Soft keyboard"*](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html)

[image: sample keyboard]

*android default keyboard*

[image: android default keyboard]

Comment: I just found a SO post that should be what I need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770099/how-do-you-disable-the-softkeyboard-key-preview-window). Could anyone close my question? Thanks!

Comment: To close a question. Just tick an answer. And write one yourself for future visitors if you feel you need to

Comment: Related: [Hide Android keyboard key preview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9996968/1267663)

Answer (score 1):

This is your preview layout.

A example of code for the preview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textStyle="bold" >

</TextView>
```

Call your preview on your keyboardView's xml:

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
```

Or you can create a class that extends KeyboardView and implement your own code for preview.

Answer (score 0):

The part that controls this resides in `LatinKeyboardView` class

```
@Override
protected boolean onLongPress(Key key) {
    if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL) {
        getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey(KEYCODE_OPTIONS, null);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onLongPress(key);
    }
}
```

The part your looking at is in the `else`.

Now this calls `super.onLongPress(key)` which resides in `KeyboardView`.

To customize override the else with respective code.

You'll find the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#onLongPress(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key))

Comment: yeah I tried to add my conditions. But theres no code there for default layout right? Like, how could I modify the popup window, say, its size, or the content it displays?

Comment: Hi I just found some relevant posts about my question like I add above in comments. But thank you for your help; appreciated it.