# Hide only preview keys on keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have searched for a solution to hide the preview key from the keyboard, if I press a button.

I know how to hide the whole keyboard with the "InputMethodService". My problem is, I want to hide the preview key, like in this thread: [Hide Android keyboard key preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996968/hide-android-keyboard-key-preview)

Is this possible without a custom KeyboardView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Android keyboard key preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996968/hide-android-keyboard-key-preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve fixed this issue by changing the focus from the EditText to the Button.